# В чем причина коммуникативно-речевой ошибки и как исправить косноязычную фразу?

Tags: грамотная-речь, коммуникативные-требования

*Крекер с сыром марки «Любятово» – вкусный и питательный завтрак в Вашем распоряжении, и значит, отличное начало трудового дня гарантировано!*

Answer (score 2):

Увы...

Ошибка, кроме косноязычья, формальная, ибо всё и так понятно: сыр марки (?! См.: [МАРКИ СЫРОВ](http://www.cheesemania.ru/info/marki-syrov)) «Любятово» иль крекер?

Далее. Убрать "Ваше превосходительство" и все лишние для слогана словеса, разбив оставшиеся на абзацы:

*Крекер с сыром марки «Любятово» – вкусный и питательный завтрак!*

*Отличное начало трудового дня гарантировано!*

---

Хотела предложить вариант подлиннее (чтоб сочинителя не слишком обижать):

*Крекер с сыром марки «Любятово»!*

*Вкусный и питательный завтрак перед вами!*

*Отличное начало трудового дня гарантировано!*

Однако... не люблю длиннот. Но это частное замечание. 
Общее: при рекламных обращениях к большому количеству людей прописное "Вы" считается моветоном.

Comment: Насчет "Вы" замечено тонко.

Comment: Браво, Галина! Теперь буду ссылаться на Вас в борьбе с ними!